# Laravel vapor github action throws permission error

Tags: laravel, github, github-actions, laravel-vapor

I'm trying to use Github Actions to deploy to vapor. I'm using the action as decribed on https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/deployments.html#deploying-from-ci.

```
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: 8.0
          tools: composer:v2
          coverage: none
          repo-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Require Vapor CLI
        run: composer global require laravel/vapor-cli
      - name: Deploy Environment
        run: vapor deploy
        env:
          VAPOR_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.VAPOR_API_TOKEN }}
```

The github action keeps failing due to this error:

```
Error Output:                                                                
  ================                                                             
  npm ERR! Error while executing:                                              
  npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/jawid-h/protobuf  
  .js.git                                                                      
  npm ERR!                                                                     
  npm ERR! Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82  
  .113.4' to the list of known hosts.                                          
  npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).                      
  npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                       
  npm ERR!                                                                     
  npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights                 
  npm ERR! and the repository exists.                                          
  npm ERR!                                                                     
  npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

I have already tried passing the GITHUB_TOKEN, but that somehow doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a ssh key error. You are not using the same ssh key as the one you imported in Github or it is not accessible in some way. You need to check `~/.ssh/id_?sa` or manually specify another file.

Or you could also switch to anonymous `https` protocol by changing the repository URL if you don't need write access by replacing:

`ssh://git@github.com/jawid-h/protobuf.js.git`

with

`https://github.com/jawid-h/protobuf.js.git`

Answer (score -1):

In my case I'm use GITLAB platform and I get the same error. I solve the issue with delete 'package-lock.json' and run a new one 'npm install'.

On package-lock.json, you find this line "lockfileVersion".

The version before solve issue:

```
"lockfileVersion": 2,
```

The version after solve issue:

```
"lockfileVersion": 1,
```

Comment: The author has clearly a problem with his ssh key, in your case you simply used npm 6 where before you were using npm 7 or npm 8